# Multiple Select Listbox Views Filter Drupal 7

Tags: 7, views

I have a view with some fields in place for instance one field is a product name. I want to make a multi-select listbox that will allow for selecting 3 of them from the list of products that's a field in the view, but haven't been able to figure it out.

Thanks,

Bill

Comment: Are you familiar with exposed filters?  When editing the filter to select the field, check the box to expose the filter and see if this is what you want.